# cz.habarta.typescript-generator : Nullable properties does'nt generate on dependent project

Tags: java, typescript, maven, generator

I have two java projects that each have classes that I want to use as a Typescript data model in a web application. My java project A is a dependency of project B. In order to generate the java and Typescript template file for project B, I am using maven. In my project B, I have a class that has as a property a class of project A. In the class of project A, I have indicated that a property can be nullable. Unfortunately, my Typescript model file does not seem to take into account the nullable annotation present in my project A. So in my Typescript model file, I do not have the possibility to use the undefined on my property.
The nullable annotation is present in my project A.

Sample code:

Project A :

```
public class DTOA extends Serializable {
   @Nullable
   private String propANull;
}
```

Project B :

```
public class DTOB extends Serializable {
   private DTOA propB;
   @Nullable
   private String propBNull;
}
```

Typescript template file :

```
export interface DTOA extends Serializable {
   propANull: string;
}

export interface DTOB extends Serializable {
   propB: propA;
   propBNull ?: string;
}
```